# Spring Kafka - Producer: TimeoutException when trying to send long message

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to send base64 encoded strings which are usually 2mb in size through Kafka. I have configured Spring Kafka producer as below:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 4194304);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.BufferExhaustedException: Failed to allocate memory within the configured max blocking time 60000 ms.
```

Things I tried:

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 90000);
```

also

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 10);
```

also

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 0);
```

Connection to kafka broker works as the topic is being auto-created. The error is persistent even after trying various combinations of the above fixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this property as well:

```
configProps.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
```

This should work well as the size of message is higher for current config, you need to extend it more.